# check keys that are set without expiry time in aws redis

Tags: redis, in-memory-database, amazon-elasticache

We can get the expiry time of a single key in Redis (aws elastic cache service) using the `TTL` command.
Similarly is there any way to find all the keys that are set without expiry from a certain time frame ( ex: since December).

Redis engine version: 2.8.21

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by 'without expiry from a certain time frame'. A key either has expiration or not. And redis only stores the actual expiration date, not when the key was created or when an expire was set

Comment: @LeoMurillo basically I was trying to see the latest keys that were set in redis.
ex: keys that were created since December.

Comment: As you have mentioned seems redis not storing the details of when the key was created. Is there any way to check last 20000 keys created

Answer (score 3):

Redis doesn't store the key's creation time. If you want, you can maintain a separate data structure in order to store this information.

For example you can use a hash that maps each key to its creation (or last update) time. It's efficient for storage, but if you want to search the last 2000 keys that were created, then this is probably not the best solution. But there is a solution!

You can use Redis' sorted sets for your purpose. For every key you create, also add that key to a sorted set, using the current timestamp as score:

```
ZADD <set_name> <timestamp> <key>
```

Later, if you want to find the latest 2000 keys, you can query the sorted set with

```
ZRANGE <set_name> -2000 -1 WITHSCORES
```

This will give you what you want to achieve (if I understand correctly), but it has a price. Every insertion to a sorted set has a time complexity of O(log(N)).
Also, you might want to consider making the two operations (adding a key value + adding the key to the set) atomic, which involves writing a short Lua script and using it for setting values, but I guess this is out of the scope of this question.